# How to change a python dictionary within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So im running into an issue trying to get my dictionary to change within a function without returning anything here is my code:

```
def load_twitter_dicts_from_file(filename, emoticons_to_ids, ids_to_emoticons):
    in_file = open(filename, 'r')
    emoticons_to_ids = {}
    ids_to_emoticons = {}

    for line in in_file:
        data = line.split()
        if len(data) > 0:
            emoticon = data[0].strip('"')
            id = data[2].strip('"')
            if emoticon not in emoticons_to_ids:
                emoticons_to_ids[emoticon] = []
            if id not in ids_to_emoticons:
                ids_to_emoticons[id] = []

            emoticons_to_ids[emoticon].append(id)
            ids_to_emoticons[id].append(emoticon)
```

basically what im trying to do is to pass in two dictionaries and fill them with information from the file which works out fine but after i call it in the main and try to print the two dictionaries it says they are empty. Any ideas?

Comment: these two lines `emoticons_to_ids = {}, ids_to_emoticons ={}` will change the reference of whatever they were pointing to before to new, empty dicts. which means the references that you passed in to the function (ie, the dicts you will later call in your code) are never touched. take those lines out and see what happens

Comment: That did the trick! thank you so much, I'm pretty new to coding but I thought that if i didn't define each one of them in the function that the code would come back with a syntax error about how they were used without being defined.

Comment: as long as you are passing dicts in, you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
def load_twitter_dicts_from_file(filename, emoticons_to_ids, ids_to_emoticons):
    …
    emoticons_to_ids = {}
    ids_to_emoticons ={}
```

These two lines replace whatever you pass to the function. So if you passed two dictionaries to the function, those dictionaries are never touched. Instead, you create two new dictionaries which are never passed to the outside.

If you want to mutate the dictionaries you pass to the function, then remove those two lines and create the dictionaries first.

Alternatively, you could also return those two dictionaries from the function at the end:

```
return emoticons_to_ids, ids_to_emoticons
```